# JDOFatalUserException: Illegal argument (on GAE J, but not on development system)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm developing an application on Google App Engine/Java.
On my development environment, the application works fine, with data stored and retrieved successfully. However, on upload to app engine, i keep getting the error "javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Illegal argument". From the stack trace, this appears to occur when i call (List query.execute()).size().
The relevant stack trace is.

```
2012-11-22 23:34:08.512
[s~qalmadev1/1.363360558551053190].<stderr>: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Illegal argument

W 2012-11-22 23:34:08.516
[s~qalmadev1/1.363360558551053190].<stderr>:    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:488)

W 2012-11-22 23:34:08.516
[s~qalmadev1/1.363360558551053190].<stderr>:    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOAdapter.getApiExceptionForNucleusException(JDOAdapter.java:1107)

W 2012-11-22 23:34:08.516
[s~qalmadev1/1.363360558551053190].<stderr>:    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryExceptionWrappers$2.get(QueryExceptionWrappers.java:72)

W 2012-11-22 23:34:08.516
[s~qalmadev1/1.363360558551053190].<stderr>:    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.hasNext(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.java:103)

W 2012-11-22 23:34:08.516
[s~qalmadev1/1.363360558551053190].<stderr>:    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveAll(LazyResult.java:120)

W 2012-11-22 23:34:08.516
[s~qalmadev1/1.363360558551053190].<stderr>:    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.size(LazyResult.java:115)

W 2012-11-22 23:34:08.516
[s~qalmadev1/1.363360558551053190].<stderr>:    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.size(StreamingQueryResult.java:151)

W 2012-11-22 23:34:08.516
[s~qalmadev1/1.363360558551053190].<stderr>:    at com.xxx.xxx.appengine.server.CreateEventServlet.doPost(CreateEventServlet.java:115)
```

Line 115 in my CreateEventServlet is the "if()" line in the code below

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("select from com.xxx.xxx.appengine.User "
        + "where key == :userid");
        List<User> result = (List<User>) query.execute(userid);
        if (result != null && result.size() > 0) { // Line 115
            user = result.get(0);
            USER_VALID = true;
        }
```

Comment: Did you explicitly set your entity name to be `com.xxx.xxx.appengine.User`? If not just use `select from User` in your query.

Comment: I personally would have printed out the nested exception, which is the real exception which would tell you the line that actually has a problem (in the publically-visible open source plugin code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("select from com.xxx. xxx.appengine.User "
    + "where key == :userid");
```

In the query, "userid" referred to a String realized through KeyFactory.keyToString().
Converting the String back to a key using KeyFactory.stringToKey() solved the issue.

Comment: You have to mark this as accepted answer. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/about) how to do this.